# Edit a branding feature

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding

We have a branding feature that was created for us by a developer. When we activate the feature the branding is applied as usual. I have a requirement to remove the breadcrumbs that it places within the top banner. What is the easiest way of doing this?
One noteworthy point is that when I open any site in SPD 2010 that has the branding I only see the 3 default master pages I do not see the MYCOMPANY.MASTER - not sure if this is normal!?

Comment: Do you know how the branding is created? A custom Visual Studio solution or is it done by using the design manager?

Comment: Its delivered as a feature - all the other work this developer did was created in VS so I imagine the branding was also created in VS

Answer (score 1):

**1st suggestion**
If you still have the Visual Studio solution. 
Make sure you have the latest version, modify it, package it and redeploy.

**2nd suggestion.**
If you don't have the Visual Studio solution... 
Can you see the master page in the master page gallery? 
http://YourDomain/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx
Make a copy, do your modifications on the copy, test your site configured with the new master page. (make sure to publish/approve your master page)

**3rd suggestion.**

A not supported 'hack' is to modify the master page on directly your hard drive. ***However this is not recommended***. You need to do this on all SharePoint servers in your farm. And it might not work if someone already did changes on the master page by using SharePoint Designer.

If you do not have the Visual Studion solution: I would go for the second solution and script the 'deployment' of your new master page to all the required sites